# How to add an unique constraint on more columns in SQL Server 2008 (R2)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE tImprumuturi
  (
     ID_Imprumut  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     DataImprumut DATE DEFAULT getdate(),
     DataScadenta AS ( dateadd(day, 2, DataImprumut) ) persisted,
     CodCD        CHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tCD(CodCd)NOT NULL,
     CodCV        CHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tCaseteVideo(CodCaseta),
     CodAb        CHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tAbonati(CodAbonat) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD, CodCV, CodAb)
  )
```

I don't want to have many of the same CodCD OR CodCV OR CodAb but never two records with the same CodCD AND CodCV AND CodAb. My code is at the top as you can see, and even if I have the instruction `CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD,CodCV,CodAb)`, it still let me to insert two or more records with the same `CodCD` and `CodCV` and `CodAb`. Below you can see my records

```
insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD20','ab9'),
      ('CV21','CD19','ab9')
```

Comment: The rows you have shown us have different `CodCD` values so they are not the same.

Comment: Although your question is not clear, based on this line *I don't want to have many of the same CodCD OR CodCV OR CodAb*, it seems you just want 3 unique constraints, one on each column.

Comment: @Martin Smith: In my records is a doble: 'CV21' and 'ab9'.

Comment: So you want `CodCV` to be unique and `CodCD` to be unique and `CodAb` to be unique individually? If so you need three constraints per [Mr Jones's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18620904/73226)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD, CodCV, CodAb)
```

The above sets a unique constraint on those three values, as if they were one value.

This would mean that the following would work:

```
set values('a', 'b', 'c'),
          ('a', 'b', 'd')
```

and the following would fail:

```
set values('a', 'b', 'c'),
          ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, you could do the following:

```
CONSTRAINT ucCodCD UNIQUE (CodCD, CodCV) 
CONSTRAINT ucCodCV UNIQUE (CodCD, CodAb) 
CONSTRAINT ucCodAb UNIQUE (CodCV, CodAb)
```

This would mean that the following would work:

```
set values('a', 'b', 'c'),
          ('a', 'd', 'e')
```

and the following would fail:

```
set values('a', 'b', 'c'),
          ('a', 'b', 'd')
```

Comment: If I insert values('CV21',**'CD20'*,'ab9'**),I don't want to insert again values('CV1',**'CD20','ab9'**)

Comment: or any other combination involving duplicate values ​​entered

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! Love you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Its working exactly as you have defined it in the table. As you have created constraint on the combination of CodCV,CodCD,CodAb, so here ('CV21','CD20','ab9') and ('CV21','CD19','ab9') would be considered as unique.(value is different for CodCD).
May be you should try creating 2 separate unique constraint as following:

```
CONSTRAINT ucCod_CD UNIQUE (CodCD) 
CONSTRAINT ucCod_CV UNIQUE (CodCV) 
CONSTRAINT ucCod_Ab UNIQUE (CodAb)
```

Comment: It seems like you don't need unique constraint on composite columns at all. Please confirm your requirement, and then if required create 3 separate constraint for 3 columns.

Comment: I've edited my code, and now you want be able to insert duplicate values at all